# How to Disable YouTube Player

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I used this code to run youtube video in my website,

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
var done = false;
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: "video id",
      playerVars: {rel: 0},
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
       }
    });
}
```

Using thing code I can track Youtube video data but **how to disable video using youtube api**, **I searching code like this(this is wrong)**

```
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
       **disable: true,**
      width: '640',
      videoId: "video id",
      playerVars: {rel: 0},
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
       }
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean by disable? Just don't prepare the player in that case.

Comment: like a disable text box, it can see but can't play

Comment: I'm not sure they have an API for that, you could overlay the player with a transparent div to block all mouse events.

Comment: Overlaying the player would be a TOS infringement.